# Add Vertical Lines With Same Encodings as "Corresponding" Curve in Altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I have a situation like this:

```py
from scipy.stats import norm as norm_dist
import numpy as np
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd


grid = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
mean_1 = 1
mean_2 = 2
dists_data = pd.concat(
    (
        pd.DataFrame({"domain": grid, "pdf": norm_dist.pdf(grid, loc=mean, scale=1)}).assign(
            distribution=f"number_{dist_number}"
        )
        for mean, dist_number in ((mean_1, 1), (mean_2, 2))
    )
)
dist_graph = (
        alt.Chart(dists_data).mark_line().encode(x="domain", y="pdf", strokeDash="distribution")
    )
```

I would like to add the two means - `mean_1` and `mean_2` - as vertical lines to the data and they should have the same color and strokeDash as the corresponding distributions - how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
(dist_graph
+ alt.Chart(dists_data).mark_rule(strokeDash=[0], color='#4c78a8').encode(x=alt.datum(mean_1))
+ alt.Chart(dists_data).mark_rule(strokeDash=[3], color='#4c78a8').encode(x=alt.datum(mean_2))
)
```

[image]

Another way would be to use the original values in the data frame and then use `transform_density` to calculate the density function and `'mean()'` to get the means.

Comment: Hey - thanks. And how do you know the `strokeDash` values?

Comment: @clog14 It is an array of the length of the stroke and the length of the space https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/mark.html#stroke (so in my example, I am only setting the length of the stroke). I tried making the means into a dataframe first and setting `strokeDash='mean:N` to avoid setting the manual value but the styles ended up looking different from the curves (maybe a line vs rule thing) so I set it manually instead.